# Magento 2: How to Set Bulk Product Position in Category?

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-products, position

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2

We are only able to set product position within Category by going to **Admin -> Products -> Categories -> Products** in Category Tab.

I have 5000 SKU's which are assigned to different Categories. If do one by one then is gonna take a long time.

Not able to find in Import/Export Product CSV this field.

I have CSV file which contains SKU's & Position. Lastly, I have to with Script.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: My agency (C3 Media) have a category position import for Magento 1. We have not yet ported this over to Magento 2, but from what we've seen Magento 2 still does not have out-of-the-box functionality to import category positions. I'll post an answer on here as and when we have a solution.

Comment: Do you still need answer for this ?